# Robolectric. Maven OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: unit-testing, maven, robolectric, android-testing

Why when I add to my pom.xml dependencies to  Robolectric library I get OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded?

My dependency:

```
         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
             <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
             <version>1.2</version>
         </dependency>
```

When I remove it all working fine.
When I add to `android-maven-plugin` next strings it has no sense

```
        <dexJvmArguments>
            <argument>-Xmx1500m</argument>
        </dexJvmArguments>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Aaron VonderHaar. [Answer on my question](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/robolectric/iY0cpwyhEik/9V3-xhGKK00J)